# jQuery selector/zoom

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a web form and trying to use jquery to enable zoom on one of the images. The form code structure is like this:

```
<asp:FormView ID="frmVwStyle" runat="server" DefaultMode="Edit"  >

    <ItemTemplate>
    ...
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <table width="690">
        <tr>
        <td width="280" align="left" valign="top">
        <div class="style-image" href='<%# ... %>'>
            <a href='' title="" id="SwatchBox" class="swatchImage" style='display:none;'><img id='SwatchImage' src='' alt='' /></a>
            <a href='<%# ... %>' zoom='<%# ... %>' rel="lightBox" title="..." id="..." class="styleImage-magnify" ><%# ...%></a>

            <img id="TargetImage" border="0" src= "images/haydensmall.jpg" style="width:250px;height:338px">

        </div>
        </td>
    ...
```

And I got the following script on top of the page.The .addimagezoom is a plugin which is working fine if the selector can select my image properly.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                        $("#TargetImage").addimagezoom({ // single image zoom
                    zoomrange: [3, 10],
                    magnifiersize: [100, 100],
                    magnifierpos: 'right',
                    cursorshade: true,
                    largeimage: 'images\\hayden.jpg' 
                });

            }
```

But it could not select the image. I also tried the following:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

            $(".style-images").find("#TargetImage").addimagezoom({  // or this one  $("#frmVwStyle").find(".style-images").find("#TargetImage").addimagezoom
                zoomrange: [3, 10],
                magnifiersize: [100, 100],
                magnifierpos: 'right',
                cursorshade: true,
                largeimage: 'images\\hayden.jpg' 
            });

        }
```

still not working. Any idea?

P.S. jquery-1.3.1 has been used in this project and I cant change it at the moment because of some incompatibilities.

Comment: Do you miss ); at the end? Can you please put pure html code, so we do not mess asp.net with this.

Comment: I see that you have place it inside an edit template - do you use UpdatePanel to open it ?

Comment: @eomeroff is better to have place the asp.net because I believe that have to do with the asp.net - the issue is inside the EditTemplate

Comment: @Aristos no. I'm not using UpdatePanel for it